# How to align lists to top right?

Tags: html, css

How to align  lists to  top right ? How can i align a list  to the top right of the div that contains it ? Will float work ?

Html

```
<div id="wall">
<ul>
<li><a href="Login.html">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="signup.html">Signup</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wall{
position:relative;
}

#wall ul li {
list-style:none;
margin-right:50px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

apply `position:relative` to the parent div. After apply the following styles for the list.

```
.list{
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
}
```

### EDIT

Thanks to Manwal for adding the jsfiddle.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1ncm2v5r/)

Comment: this worked but I've got two lists and they are overlapping any idea to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `float: right` will work.
http://jsfiddle.net/k0r1dj10/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/k0r1dj10/6/ with more than one drop down.

Additionally what might be better is to set the outer div to `position: relative` as well as the inner div to `position: absolute` and `top: 0` as well as `right: 0`.
http://jsfiddle.net/k0r1dj10/3/

To use more than one div in the `relative` way, you have to use another parent div. This requires you know the width, tho. http://jsfiddle.net/k0r1dj10/5/

Comment: this works for one list but if i add another one they will overlap

Comment: Thanks all of you  helped me

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of `li` then use `float:right;` - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k0r1dj10/4/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="wall">
<ul>
<li><a href="signup.html">Signup</a></li>
<li><a href="Login.html">Login</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wall{
position:relative;
}

#wall ul li {
list-style:none;
margin-right:50px;
position:relative;
float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1cm0621n/)

CSS:

```
        #wall{
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wall">
<ul>
<li><a href="Login.html">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="signup.html">Signup</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.left_box1 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px; 
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: right;

}
```